# Issues with set images in ViewPager pages

Tags: android, resources, android-imageview

I'm getting "Source not found" error while trying to set image resource for my ImageView in ViewPager. But I don't have error if I set image in XML. However if I set image in XML, it's not shown while I'm running app.
I'm using [viewpagerindictor](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) lib and android-support-v13.jar.
Activity code

```
public class DataActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int obj_id, type_id, node_id;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    Bundle ex = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (ex != null) {
        obj_id = ex.getInt("obj");
        type_id = ex.getInt("type");
        node_id = ex.getInt("node");
    }

    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

    View page = inf.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
    ImageView im = (ImageView)page.findViewById(R.id.im_v_obj1);
    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.obj1));
    pages.add(page);

    PageAdapter pa = new PageAdapter(pages);
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    TitlePageIndicator tpi = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    vp.setAdapter(pa);
    tpi.setViewPager(vp);

    }

}
```

PageAdapter code

```
public class PageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

List<View> pages = null;

private static String[] titles = new String[]
        {
            "Object 1"
        };

public PageAdapter(List<View> pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

public String getPageTitle( int position )
{
    return titles[ position ];
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int pos) {
    View v = pages.get(pos);
    ((ViewPager)collection).addView(v, 0);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem (View collection, int pos, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager)collection).removeView((View)view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v.equals(obj);
}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-fragment adapter solution that might work for you.  Please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager).